# How do I set the 'ServerCertificateValidationCallback' property back to its default behavior?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ssl, ssl-certificate

I use the following line of code within a single method to explicitly check and trust an SSL cert from the following host: MyTrustedCompany.com:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(obj As [Object], certificate As X509Certificate, chain As X509Chain, errors As SslPolicyErrors) (certificate.Subject.Contains("CN=MyTrustedCompany.com"))
```

No problem with the code -> works perfectly 100%.

The problem is, it is too far reaching. I thought its scope would only be within the method I decalred it, but apparently it is a Shared property on the 'ServicePointManager' object, and must then persist for the entire application, which I do not want.

The problem is later I am calling web services of mine, etc and getting the "Could not establish a trust relationship..." exception. This is because in the line of code above I check for the host name of an SSL cert specefic to that method. I quickly tested Returning 'True' from the callback so all certs would be trusted instead of checking for a specefic name (i.e. MyTrustedCompany) and subsiquent requests **worked**.  This is how I know this callback assignment reaches father than that single method.  Sure I could extend the callback to include all other certitificate names, but what I would *rather* do is set the 'ServerCertificateValidationCallback' back to its default behavior. Like the pseudo code below:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Nothing  'Default checking behavior
```

How do I remove the custom validation and set it back to its default behavior?  Thanks!

Comment: You could probably set it equal to a function that does what the default behavior is: When custom validation is not used, the certificate name is compared with host name used to create the request. For example, if Create(String) was passed a parameter of "https://www.contoso.com/default.hmtl", the default behavior is for the client to check the certificate against www.contoso.com. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback.aspx

Comment: A similar question has an answer which looks good https://stackoverflow.com/a/44803221/57428

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This actually appears to work (as simple as it is) and makes the object behave in its default manner.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Nothing
```

Comment: Have you figured out if there is any way to make this thread-safe? Since this thing is static, I would assume, every thread that uses web services would call your delegate while it's set.

Comment: (Realizing this is really old...) Are you sure that works? Setting to null in C# [reportedly sends everything through](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8722292/1028230).

Comment: Yes it did work setting the behavior back to its default in that it would then begin to discriminate against SSL certificates and _not_ allow everything through. It was the assigned callback method that had the functionality to `return true` which was what allowed everything through.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to only return true for certain URLs,
but otherwise, this does what you want, leaving the possibility of using multiple delegates.  The logic for each callback could include a check via reflection so that the callback only returns true when called from certain components, thus creating a sort of tunnel between certain URLs and certain applications.

One way to use this code: 
1. Define the mIgnoreBadCertificates delegate early in your object's life
2. Set a property containing the 'beSecure' code true
3. Send the Http Request.
4. Set the property false.  This is very important, and should be implemented in a way that guarantees it gets called.  The IDisposable pattern is one option.

```
 private System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback mIgnoreBadCertificates = new
    System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
      delegate { return true; });

if (beSecure)
    {   //require secure communications
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -= mIgnoreBadCertificates;
        Iwds.EventLogger.LogVeryFrequentEvent("Requiring Good Certificates from Remote Sites");
    }
    else
    {   /// Allow connections to SSL sites that have unsafe certificates.
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += mIgnoreBadCertificates;
        Iwds.EventLogger.LogVeryFrequentEvent("Ignoring Bad Certificates from Remote Sites");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

A key point to solving your problem is the fact that the `sender` parameter to the `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` is the `WebRequest`. You can check the sender against your webrequest so you only do checking for your webrequest. Here is my (relatively untested) solution:

```
// Main Code

request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://example.com");

using(var validator = new WebRequestCertificateValidator(request))
{
    // etc...
}

// WebRequestCertificateValidator Class

public sealed class WebRequestCertificateValidator : IDisposable
{
    private bool disposed;

    private WebRequest request;

    private RemoteCertificateValidationCallback callback;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a certificate validator that allows all certificates for the supplied web request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The WebRequest to validate for.</param>
    public WebRequestCertificateValidator(WebRequest request) : this(request, null)
    {
        //
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a certificate validator that only allows certificates for the supplied web request of the callback returns true.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The WebRequest to validate for.</param>
    /// <param name="callback">The delegate that will be called to validate certificates for the WebRequest.</param>
    public WebRequestCertificateValidator(WebRequest request, RemoteCertificateValidationCallback callback)
    {
        this.disposed = false;

        this.request = request;

        this.callback = callback;

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += this.InternalCallback;
    }

    private bool InternalCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        WebRequest request = sender as WebRequest;

        if(request != null)
        {
            if(request == this.request)
            {
                if(this.callback != null)
                {
                    return this.callback(sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors);
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(!this.disposed)
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -= this.InternalCallback;

            this.callback = null;

            this.request = null;

            this.disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class OAuthRequestHandler : WebRequestHandler
{
    public OAuthRequestHandler() : base()
    {
        base.ServerCertificateValidationCallback  += this.InternalCallback;
    }

    private bool InternalCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return certificate.Subject.Contains("CN=MyTrustedCompany.com");
    }
}
```

and in my program.cs commandline test:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new OAuthRequestHandler());
responseString = await client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:2345");
```

It is possible to do more with the certificate and sender parameters but the OP asked for the above.

Comment: To be precise the above solution introduces a serious security issue, the condition should be: return (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None) && certificate.Subject.Contains("CN=MyTrustedCompany.com");

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way to make sure that the custom callback is reliably reverted and the whole thing is also thread safe it to put the code which needs a subverted callback into a separate process. In many cases this is quite easy to do - you could for example run the separate process code using `Process` class and passing it a command line. gRPC or WCF are other communication options.

This way only the separate process sets the custom callback and the main process is unaffected.