# Resetting ServerCertificateValidationCallback

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ssl-certificate

I need to access a REST service that has an SSL certificate which isn't really valid. So I added the following in my code:

```
 System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
    ((sender, cert, chain, errors) =>
       cert.Subject.Contains("soap.example.com"));
```

After that I do what I have to do to send the request to REST service.

Everything is fine.

But lateron I need to connect to a different domain (which has a valid SSL certificate). The the latter fails because of a certificate error that disappears if I restart the IIS and only comes back after the code segment displayed above is called again:

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could
> not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. --->
> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
> certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

So after sending the request to the REST service with invalid certificate, how can I make sure, the normal behavior is working again?

Simply resetting to `ServerCertificateValidationCallback=null` does not seem to work.

(I am fully aware about the dangers of the CallBack)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call default ServerCertificateValidationCallback inside customized validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679120/how-to-call-default-servercertificatevalidationcallback-inside-customized-valida)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
        ((sender, cert, chain, errors) => 
        errors == SslPolicyErrors.None || cert.Subject.Contains("soap.example.com"));
```

should do the trick.

Comment: That looks promising. Will try that.

Comment: The no-errors check is good.  The other side of the or could use some shoring up.  The problem being that this would consider `thatsfunny.imnot.soap.example.com` as a valid certificate for `google.com`, since it doesn't assert that `RemoteCertificateNameMatch` isn't set.  (And even then things get tricky)

Comment: I agree @bartonjs . Nonetheless, I kept that code to be consistent with the question as asked.